# NtQueryInformationFile returns incorrect allocation size

Tags: winapi, filesize, ntdll

I use [NtQueryInformationFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556646.aspx) with [FILE_STANDARD_INFORMATION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545855.aspx) struct to retrieve the **allocation size** of file. But for small files it returns incorrect<sup>1</sup> result. For example text file with size 1 byte returns 8 bytes allocation size, instead 4096 bytes. Where is problem?

---

<sup>1</sup> *I'm assuming that this value is incorrect, because Explorer (on Windows XP Checked Build in my case) the* size on disk *reports higher figures (4096 bytes for a file with size 1).*

Answer (score -3):

file size in EndOfFile member. AllocationSize - this is how many disk space allocated for file -

> Usually, this value is a multiple of the sector or cluster size of the
>   underlying physical device.

Comment: Thanks. But how this answer my question? Example: I have no problem with file of 1024 bytes size - returns 4096 bytes, but for 1 byte file size returns 8 bytes instead 4096 bytes.

Comment: very simply - if you need file size - look for EndOfFile member - here exactly will be file size

Comment: ok, understand - but this is already internal for FS. say if file have size <= 8 byte - ntfs return you 8, if file size <= 16 - ntfs retutn you 16 - in what here problem ? why you decide that whole cluster must be allocate for this file ? this is "usually" but not mandatory

Comment: Problem is computing allocation size, how I trust NtQueryInformationFile, when for small files returns incorrect allocation size? Where is this 'feature' documented?

Comment: "how I trust NtQueryInformationFile" - so how i can trust FS if FS return me "incorrect" allocation size ??

Comment: Because fsutil returns 4096 bytes per sector, also Explorer reports size on disk - aka allocation size 4096 bytes.

Comment: Probably dont know what is allocation size.

Comment: "4096 bytes per sector" - so what ? are file must ALWAYS take multiple sector size ?

Comment: Yes, sure, allocation size must be in sector size  boundary.

Comment: no, must not. this is internal for FS implementation

Comment: OK, you dont know nothing about this.

Comment: are you sure ? ))

Comment: @user2120666: The allocation size must be a multiple of the **cluster** size. The cluster size can be larger than the sector size. You can query both values using `fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo <volume>`.

Comment: Yes, my mistake - must be on cluster size, not sector size. But I already doing fsutil and returns 4096 bytes, but NtQueryInformationFile returns 8 bytes allocation size.

Comment: @IInspectable - "The allocation size must be a multiple of the cluster size" - where documented that this be MUST ? not usual but MUST ? look say for ntfs src code. in all case FILE_STANDARD_INFORMATION filled by FS driver - he better know :)

Comment: @IInspectable - i just look under debugger on small file (9 bytes) for it FSRTL_ADVANCED_FCB_HEADER - and in it AllocationSize==16 byte and FileSize == 9 byte. so this is "error' in ntfs driver ? :)

Comment: Thanks, you now understand about my problem.

Comment: NTFS can store small files in the MFT itself.

Comment: Yes I know but why not return MFT record segment size (1024), or why is not documented about this?

Comment: @user2120666 - look - i just looked this under debugger - http://imgur.com/3zAbmHt

Comment: Thanks. So is better round up value  to cluster size as Explore does.

Comment: NtQueryInformationFile -> IRP(IRP_MJ_QUERY_INFORMATION) -> Ntfs[Fat]CommonQueryInformation -> Ntfs[Fat]QueryStandardInfo - `Buffer->AllocationSize = Fcb->Header.AllocationSize;` - look for fastfat source how minimum - you not trust filesystem ?

Comment: "So is better round up value to cluster size as Explore does" - better for what ?? and say in my case (win10) explorer round down . may be this is "better" ?

Comment: In my case Explorer (WIN XP Checked) round up. Yes I trust file system, but If I want imitate Explorer, I must follow Explorer.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh148159.aspx:  If the file is neither compressed nor sparse, then the Size on disk is the file size reported by the Find­First­File function rounded up to the nearest cluster.

Comment: @user2120666 - i good know what is size on disk and how this is different from file size

Comment: You have better tip how get allocation size?

Comment: @user2120666 - NtQueryInformationFile return exactly what return FS - are can be better tip that FS return ? you need use  `FILE_STANDARD_INFORMATION.AllocationSize` AS IS

Comment: But I will see many reports why my application returns another Size on disk (allocation size) than Explorer.

Comment: @user2120666 - so reply that explorer return rounded size some time, when you return exactly size

Comment: @JonathanPotter - yes - "This is accurate for FAT file systems, but it is naive for NTFS" "Furthermore, the "Size on disk" is naive" - however `FILE_STANDARD_INFORMATION.AllocationSize` - returned by FS and he is the best know what size allocated

Comment: @RbMm: The question is not, how to retrieve the exact size on disk. The question is: How does Explorer display the size on disk. And it is explained in the link posted by Jonathan Potter.

Comment: @IInspectable - this is already was after OP edit self question.